# Getting output as a character instead of a number in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm relatively new to 8086. I was making a 4 function calculator using procedures. 
When I enter the input as:

first number:1

second number:1

choice:1 (1 is for addition)

I get the output as 'b'.
Getting to my question, can anyone tell me why this is happening and what changes I should make to get my output as '2'?

```
DATA SEGMENT
    MSG1 DB 'Enter a number:$'          
    MSG2 DB 'Enter another number:$'    
    MSG3 DB '1 for addition$'
    MSG7 DB 'Enter choice(1-4):$'
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT 
ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA
START:
MOV AX,DATA          ;initialize DS     
MOV DS,AX            

MOV DX,OFFSET MSG1   ;print msg1
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

MOV AH,01H           ;get user input part 1
INT 21H               

MOV BL,AL            ;store 1st number in BL

PRINTN 

MOV DX,OFFSET MSG2   ;print msg2
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

MOV AH,01H           ;get user input part 2
INT 21H         

MOV CL,AL            ;store 2nd number in CL 

PRINTN

MOV DX,OFFSET MSG3   ;print msg3
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H           

MOV DX,OFFSET MSG7   ;print msg7
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

MOV AH,01H           ;get user input part 3 (choice for add,sub etc)
INT 21H     

MOV DL,AL            ;store user's choice in dl

CMP DL,1             ;basically if-else 
JE L1                           

L1:PRINTN
CALL ADDITION        ;call addition proc
HLT


ADDITION PROC
    ADD BL,CL             ;add the numbers and store in bl
    MOV DX,OFFSET MSG8    ;print MSG8
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H

    MOV DL,BL             ;mov sum to dl
    MOV AH,02H            ;ah=2 for o/p
    INT 21H               ;interrupt  
    RET                   ;go back to main
ADDITION ENDP
```

Note: I've added the minimum code necessary, in case you want the entire code, let me know.

Comment: You need to convert between text and number. See also [man ascii](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html) and the gazillion examples on SO.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/   `'1' + '1'` == `49 + 49` == `98` == `'b'`

Comment: Thanks guys, very cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> MOV AH,01H           ;get user input part 1
> INT 21H               
> MOV BL,AL            ;store 1st number in BL
> ```

The comment *"store 1st **number** in BL"* is the culpritt here! What you get back from this DOS input function is a **character**. Best convert the character into the number that it represents. Simply subtract 48.

**Shouldn't you verify that the input was indeed one of "0", "1", "2", ... , "9" ?**

```
mov ah, 01h  ;get user input part 1
int 21h
sub al, '0'  ;'0' is the same as 48 (30h)
mov bl, al   ;store 1st number in BL
```

Do the same for the second number.
Now all calculations can act upon true numbers.
To display the (single character) result you need to convert the number back into a character. Simply add 48.

```
mov dl, b    ;mov sum to dl
add dl, '0'  ;'0' is the same as 48 (30h)
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
```